# Page control is not Updating

Tags: ios, xcode6, uipagecontrol

i want to implement the page control in my application ,
What i did is i place a page control from the storyboard ,and i make outlet for that ,and instance variable for scrollview also .,

```
     -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
        {

     int totalEnteries = (int)self.arrGraphData.count;
     NSUInteger entriesPerPage = 7;
     int noOfPages = totalEnteries/entriesPerPage;
     if(totalEnteries % entriesPerPage!= 0)
     {
      noOfPages++;
     }


   NSUInteger numberPages =noOfPages;

   self.pageControl.numberOfPages =numberPages;

   CGFloat offset = self.scrollView1.contentOffset.x;
   CGFloat pageSize= self.scrollView1.frame.size.width;
   int page = floor((offset-pageSize/2)/pageSize);
   self.pageControl.currentPage =page;

   }
```

the above coding only i did,while i running my project ,i can able to see the page control ,but it is not updating when i scroll to next page ,please help me to do this ,and say what i did wrong in this coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you

Don't forget to set the **UIScrollView's delegate = self** (or wherever you have the selector below).

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width; // you need to have a **iVar** with getter for scrollView
        float fractionalPage = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
        NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page; // you need to have a **iVar** with getter for pageControl
    }
```

Comment: thanks@Pramod Tapaniya ,one more help ,i want to set condition for that ,like i page is one then the page control should be in hide ,if it has more than one means it will should the page control

Comment: @ChandrikaVisvesh check checkbox of 'hides for single page' property of  pagecontrol from the storyboard

Comment: @ChandrikaVisvesh if you get a complete answer from me then set this answer as a correct answer. Thanx...

Comment: thanks @Pramod Tapaniya , now i got the correct result .